error: could not load module 'unicode' in MikTex for asymptote
I have a problem with rendering the .asy file asymptote in miktex, when I try to render I get this error: could not load module 'unicode'. How can I solve this problem?


Welcome to TeX.SE. Please don't add the code as a screenshot. Copy the code into a code block instead so it can be used to answer the question.

Asymptote does not ship with a module called unicode.
